# Intended usage of /network-map/ack-parameters: parameters Hash and(?) NodeKey?

Tags: corda, cordite

The Corda Node can accept the new network parameters update with the **/network-map/ack-parameters** post request. The Parameters Hash is sent to the network operator with this request.

Therefore, there are 2 questions:

1. Is it intended that the network operator can know from which Node this acceptance request came? By other word, how the network operator can know which node accepted the new network parameters update?
2. If I check the Cordite Network Map Service implementation(https://gitlab.com/cordite/network-map-service/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/io/cordite/networkmap/service/NetworkMapService.kt#L294), the submitted parameter is interpreted as a key for NodeInfo in the NodeInfo storage, instead of being interpreted as Parameters Hash. It looks inconsistent with how the Corda defines the **/ack-parameters** request parameters. Does Cordite implementation of Network Map Service is adequate on this aspect?

Answer (score 0):

I'll do my best to use my own intuition to answer these as they're quite specific.

1. Yes it's intended for the network operator to know where the acceptance request comes from as it's part of properly managing the parties on the network. You can actually check this out in the corda source code here to see how the "doorman" handles new node participants: https://github.com/corda/corda
2. I don't think cordite needs to be semantically exactly similar to the way that Corda does it. That being said it's certainly adequate.